# Make assertEqual not fail on RuntimeErrors starting with specific string

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am writing unittests in Python using `assertEqual`:

```
def test_SetOwner(self, owner):
   self.objectid.SetOwner(owner)
   self.assertEqual(self.objectid.GetOwner(), owner)
```

This works in the majority of cases, but under some specific circumstances this fails with a `RuntimeError` starting with `Could not execute...`. However, this is expected en should not trigger an error in the unittest suite.

Is there a method to somehow make `assertEqual` not fail on RuntimeErrors starting with this specific string while still catching all other RuntimeErrors? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Couldn't you wrap it in a `try:`/`except RuntimeError as exc:` block and then pass or reraise depending upon `exc.args`?

Comment: Why is your unit test nondeterministic? Yes, you can catch the RuntimeError then check `e.args[0]` for the desired string, but in general, unit tests are supposed to run through a very specific scenario to check the result of a piece of code, and having the unit test permit two *very* different behaviors seems to me like a code smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a `try/except` block, and check for the two cases separately.

```
def test_SetOwner(self, owner):
    self.objectid.SetOwner(owner)
    try:
        owner_prime = self.objectid.GetOwner()
    except RuntimeError as e:
        self.assertTrue(e.args[0].startswith("Could not execute"))
    else:
        self.assertEqual(owner, owner_prime)
```

But as mentioned in my comment above,  this doesn't look like a very good unit test. What if, as an example, a bug gets introduced to `GetOwner()` at some point, so that it always raises the "Could not execute" `RuntimeError`? That would almost certainly not be the desired behavior, but your test will continue passing.

Comment: I'd add that, if this non-deterministic behaviour depends on some external program/resource, the OP should definitely mock it to obtain a more reliable tests on well-known situations.